# Two ways of decomposing a tetragon into triangles: Relation of their angles.

Tags: geometry

Consider a tetragon. It can be divided into two triangles in two different ways. Consider one of the two divisions. The angles of the corners of the two triangles determine the tetragon up to scaling. Is there any neat formula that expresses those angles of one division in terms of the angles of the other division?

I worked up the formula by picking a coordinate system and using tangent functions, but it's quite a mess (like the inverse tangent of some complicated stacked fraction of tangents). If someone knows a simpler expression that would be helpful!

Comment: Please include your formula, messy though it may be. It might be easier for someone to simplify it than to effectively re-derive the result over again.

Comment: apparently  tetragon is going to be a convex quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the angles and sides as below.

[image]

Since the angles in a triangle add up to $\pi$, we get four equations in eight variables:

$$\eqalign{\alpha_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \gamma_1 &= \pi\cr
           \alpha_2 + \gamma_2 + \delta_1 + \delta_2 &= \pi\cr
           \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta_1 + \delta_1 &= \pi\cr
           \beta_2 + \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \delta_2 &= \pi\cr}$$

However, these are not independent (equation 1 + equation 4 = equation 2 + equation 3), so you can only solve these for three of the variables in terms of the other five, e.g.

$$ \eqalign{\alpha_1 &= -\beta_1 + \gamma_2 + \delta_2 \cr
            \alpha_2 &= \pi - \gamma_2 - \delta_1 - \delta_2\cr
            \beta_2 &= \pi - \gamma_1 - \gamma_2 - \delta_2\cr} $$

We need one more equation, which can come from the law of sines:

$$ \frac{AC}{BD} = \frac{\sin(\gamma_1)}{\sin(\alpha_1)} \frac{\sin(\alpha_2)}{\sin(\gamma_2)} = \frac{\sin(\delta_1)}{\sin(\beta_1)} \frac{\sin(\beta_2)}{\sin(\delta_2)} $$

which then, after substituting for $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2$, can be solved for $\gamma_1$ as rather a mess:

$$ \gamma_1 = \text{arccot}\left(-{\frac {\sin \left( \delta_{{1}}+\delta_{{2}}+\gamma_{{2}} \right) 
\sin \left( \beta_{{1}} \right) \sin \left( \delta_{{2}} \right) }{
\sin \left( \delta_{{1}} \right) \sin \left( \gamma_{{2}}+\delta_{{2}}
 \right) \sin \left( -\delta_{{2}}-\gamma_{{2}}+\beta_{{1}} \right) 
\sin \left( \gamma_{{2}} \right) }}-{\frac {\cos \left( \gamma_{{2}}+
\delta_{{2}} \right) }{\sin \left( \gamma_{{2}}+\delta_{{2}} \right) }}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks for that great answer! mostly wanted to make sure that i'm not missing a very simple way to do it, which doesn't seem to be the case. Your expression is a bit nicer than the one I had gotten though..

Answer (score 1):

We will assume the tetragon is convex and label its vertices and angles as illustrated below:

[image: A tetragon]

The problem at hand is given angles $a,b,c,d$, how to figure out the angles $e,f,g,h$.

In terms of the angle between the two diagonals, $\theta$, the expression of $e,f,g,h$ are very simple.

$$( e, f, g, h ) = ( \theta - a, \pi - \theta - b, \pi - \theta - c, \theta - d )$$
Everything comes down to finding the value of $\theta$.

Choose a coordinate system so that $A = (0,0)$, $C = (1,0)$, let
$$\alpha = \cot a, \beta = \cot b, \gamma = \cot c, \delta = \cot d$$

If $h$ is the height of $\triangle ACD$ with respect base $AC$, it is easy to see
$$1 = |AC| = h \cot a + h \cot b = h(\alpha+\beta)\quad\implies\quad h = \frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}$$
This implies the vertex $D$ has coordinate $(h\cot a,h) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}, \frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}\right)$.
By a similar argument, we find $B = \left(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \delta}, - \frac{1}{\gamma + \delta}\right)$. As a result,

$$
\cot\theta = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} - \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}}{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta} + \frac{1}{\gamma+\delta}}
= \frac{\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta}
= \frac{\cot a \cot d - \cot b\cot c}{\cot a + \cot b + \cot c + \cot d}
$$
As one can see, even tough $\theta$ is arc-cotangent of some complicated ratios of cotangents of $a,b,c,d$, that ratio does possess certain obvious symmetry.

By the way, if one reverse the roles of $a,b,c,d$ and $e, g, f, h$ in above argument, one can deduce following interesting identity among the cotangents:

$$\frac{\cot a \cot d - \cot b\cot c}{\cot a + \cot b + \cot c + \cot d}
= \frac{\cot e \cot h - \cot g\cot f}{\cot e + \cot f + \cot g + \cot h}$$